# models for input and models for views, do you separate? c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop

I have Some model, for example: `RequestModel`

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }

    public int CategoryKey { get; set; }
    public int SubCategoryKey { get; set; }
    public int AreaKey { get; set; }   
}
```

This model I use to get input from some html form.

`CategoryKey`, `SubCategoryKey`, and `AreaKey`, are codes for the Category, Subcategory and the Area values.

For display purposes I need to show the `CategoryValue`, `SubCategoryValue` and `AreaValue`. So I use the same model for my View and added the three fields to it.

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }

    public int CategoryKey { get; set; }
    public int SubCategoryKey { get; set; }
    public int AreaKey { get; set; }

    public String CategoryValue { get; set; }
    public String SubCategoryValue { get; set; }
    public String AreaValue { get; set; }
}
```

I'm thinking of separate it to the following classes:

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
}

public class RequestInputModel : RequestModel
{
    public int CategoryKey { get; set; }
    public int SubCategoryKey { get; set; }
    public int AreaKey { get; set; }
}

public class RequestDisplayModel : RequestModel
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public String CategoryValue { get; set; }
    public String SubCategoryValue { get; set; }
    public String AreaValue { get; set; }
}
```

What do you think? is it really necessary? do you do this separation between classes for input and classes for display?

Comment: I don't think there is a general answer that would fit to all use cases.As a rule of thumb I would say: If you are working on a small project that does not have a long lifetime and you don't expect many changes, the simplest solution may be the best. If you work on a large scale system, seperating you logic as much as possible helps you a lot in keeping it maintainable.

Comment: you seem to be confusing several different design paradigms together,  your question asks about modelling which is MVC or MVVM, but your code example is about inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The General Best Practice is that you have your Data in the model. ie information that you need to save to a file or database, you then have your business logic on a View Model, this would be things like the Fullname being a First + Surname and the like, so data that needs to be displayed but not saved
then you have your View on top that formats and styles your output

so you would have

```
public class PersonModel
{
    string firstName;
    string Surname;
    DateTime DateOfBirth
}
public class PersonDisplayViewModel
{
    PersonModel Model;
    string FullName
    {
        get{return Model.firstname + " " + Model.Surname;}
    }
    int Age
    {
        get{return (DateTime.Today() - Model.DateOfBirth).TotalYears;}
    }
}
public class PersonEditViewModel
{
    PersonModel Model;
    string FirstName {
        get{return Model.FirstName;}
        set{Model.FirstName = value;}
    }
    string Surname{
        get{return Model.Surname;}
        set{Model.Surname= value;}
    }
    DateTime DateOfBirth{
        get{return Model.DateOfBirth;}
        set{Model.Surname= DateOfBirth;}
    }

}
```

The reason for this is that the same core data may be used in many places, say you have a search screen that shows Full name and age and an editing screen that lets you edit first and last name and date of birth. they have the same core data of person but they present the data in different ways. also say you were doing something for a School and wanted to make sure a students age is <16 but you also have staff that have to be >18. you can't put this age filter on the person Model as a person can be any age, but would fit perfectly well on the view model that is defining what can and can't be written to the under lying model

the same is true for views if you have a version of your app in USA you want to use American Date Format ie mm-dd-yyyy but the same app in UK would need the dd-mm-yyyy format does this have any effect on the underlying data or business logic? No it just changes the appearance of the data so goes in the veiw